# Probability for a class problem

Tags: probability

Question: A college has 10 non-overlapping time slots for its courses, and blithely assigns courses to time slots randomly and independently. A student randomly chooses 3 of the courses to enroll in (from the PTP, to avoid getting fined). What is the probability that there is a conflict in the student's schedule?

My answer:

Total number of possible combinations for 3 courses in 10 timeslots:
EG. for one combination

c | c c ||||||||

where c= class and each | = boundary between two timeslots (totally, 10 timeslots and thus 9 lines).
Therefore, total number of possible combinations = $\binom{9+3}{3}$

Total number of non-conflicting combinations = $\binom{10}{3}$

P(conflict) = 1-P(no conflict) = $1-\frac{\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{9+3}{3}}$

This is not the answer, and my question is WHY MY ANSWER IS WRONG.

Answer (score 3):

The stars and bars approach doesn't yield equi-probable cases.

It should be evident that a pattern like c c c | | | | | | | | |
will be much rarer than a more evenly distributed one like c | | | c | | | c | | |

The appropriate model would be to roll a $10$ sided die $3$ times.

See also a parallel case explained in greater detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931069/correct-approach-to-evaluate-probability/1931619#1931619)

Comment: For the following problem, why are the different patterns equi-probable then?
How many ways are there to put 6 indistinguishable particles into 6 distinguishable boxes?

Answer: $ \binom{11}{6} $


Is its probability of this pattern p p p | | p p | p | | the same as that of the pattern p p p p p p | | | | | ?

Comment: What has been asked is "how many ways", not "how many equi-probable ways", and the patterns thus generated are *not* equi-probable.